# numeric approximation to find maximum of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

is there a fast numeric algorithm to approximate the maximum of an given function in an interval [x,y] without calculate the derivation of the function?

I only know about solver to calculate the roots (like the Brent method)

greetings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If its a function of one variable, then use the [golden section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) search.
If its is function of multiple vars, then use [Downhill Simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder-Mead_method)

Comment: yeah! that's it! thank you :)